# communication between RFID (epc) tags and devices that have BLE

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rfid

Is there a way to create communication between devices (phones) that have bluetooth 4.0 and different RFID tags like EPS tags on products, without using extra hardware?

I search for an API that allows to use devices that have BLE (like the last android and apple phone) to scan products RFID tags and get information from them.

I know that bluetooth 4.0 uses RFID so I think that this kind of API exists, but I couldn't find it.

Also, if you used any API like this and you have the experience, please write some pros and cons, because I also search for the best that exists.

thanks very much!

Comment: I think you are confusing RFID with NFC which has its own protocol/frequencies separate from Bluetooth LTE. See the frequency chart: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely different wireless technology.

tl;dr

**No**

Bluetooth is an active transfer wireless socket protocol, and RFID is a short wave IDentification system, they do not operate on the same frequency.

I am unsure what hardware the newest iWare has, but many new Android phones have an RFID / Contactless Smart Card devices built into them, in addition to one for BLE.